# Animating button backgroundColor while maintaining cornerRadius

Tags: java, android

I am animating the scale and backgroundColor of a Button:

```xml
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:ordering="together">
    <objectAnimator
        android:propertyName="scaleX"
        android:duration="600"
        android:valueTo="0.8"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"/>
    <objectAnimator
        android:propertyName="scaleY"
        android:duration="600"
        android:valueTo="0.8"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"/>
    <objectAnimator
        android:duration="600"
        android:propertyName="backgroundColor"
        android:valueFrom="@color/bgBtnConnect"
        android:valueTo="@color/bgBtnConnecting"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"/>
</set>
```

```java
public void anim() {
    AnimatorSet firstSet = (AnimatorSet) AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(context, R.animator.connect_button);
    firstSet.setTarget(btn);
    firstSet.start();
}
```

Initially this button has a drawable set as its background:

```
 android:background="@drawable/button"
```

```xml
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@color/black" />
    <corners android:radius="40dp" />
</shape>
```

When I animate the button it does not maintain this cornerRadius, probably because it is overwriting this background drawable. How do I maintain the cornerRadius during the animation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right, it is overwriting this background drawable.

In your case, that shape drawable is not necessary, you can round the corners as follows:

```
btn.setClipToOutline(true);
btn.setOutlineProvider(new ViewOutlineProvider() {
    @Override
    public void getOutline(View view, Outline outline) {
        outline.setRoundRect(0, 0, view.getWidth(), view.getHeight(), radiusPx);
    }
});
```